# DTIME and PSPACE

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Most people believe that $\mathsf{P} \not= \mathsf{PSPACE}$ and $\mathsf{PSPACE} \not=\mathsf{EXP}$.

Is there a function $f$ such that $f(n) < 2^n$ and $f(n) > p(n)$ for every polynomial $p$ (and rather large $n$) such that most people believe that
$\mathsf{DTIME}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{PSPACE}$ ?

Comment: Do you want a bigger upper bound than $2^n$? I'm not sure about common belief that $\mathsf{PSPACE} \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(2^n)$. Note that $\mathsf{EXP}$ can be a bit ambiguous or unclear, but it means $\bigcup_k \mathsf{DTIME}(2^{n^k})$.

Comment: @usul no, I want a bigger upper bound than $\mathsf{P}$

Comment: My comment might have been unclear, I meant do you want to take out $2^n$ and replace it with something bigger, or are you implying that most people believe $\mathsf{PSPACE} \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(2^n)$? (If so, is it true?)

Comment: @usul do you think that $ \bigcup_k \mathsf{DTIME}(n^{k \log n}) \subseteq \mathsf{PSPACE}$?

Comment: I wouldn't believe that $TIME(n^{\omega(1)})$ is contained in $PSPACE$...

Comment: I am not sure this question is appropriate here, as it is opinion based, unless we could somehow conduct a poll..

Comment: I am pretty sure that if $g$ is a function that eventually dominates all recursive functions, then $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^{g^{-1}(n)})$ is included in PSPACE (and in fact coincides with P). Presumably, some slower growing and computable function in place of $g$ will work, too. You should probably require $f(n)$ to be time-constructible or something, so that $\mathrm{DTIME}(f(n))$ is strictly larger than P.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I would like to see for example a language in $\mathsf{DTIME}(n^{\log n})$ such that we do not about it belonging to $\mathsf{PSPACE}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $DTIME(n^{g^{-1}(n)})\supseteq TIME(n^{\omega(1)})$?

Comment: @AJ. What do you mean by $\mathrm{TIME}(n^{\omega(1)})$? Taken by its face value, it denotes the set of all computable predicates, as arbitrarily fast growing functions are $\omega(1)$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek sorry bad query there.

Answer (score 4):

Since no clarification seems to be forthcoming, let me just answer the question as is, for the record.

The answer is yes, one can prove there is such a function. (Which doesn’t necessarily mean most people will believe it, but anyway.)

Let $g\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be an increasing function that eventually majorizes every recursive function, and $h$ be its inverse; more precisely,
$$h(n)=\min\{m:g(m)\ge n\}.$$
Then $h$ is an unbounded nondecreasing function with the property that every recursive function eventually majorized by $h$ is bounded. Put
$$f(n)=n^{h(n)}.$$
Then $f$ is (barely) superpolynomial, and I claim
$$\mathrm{DTIME}(f(n))\subseteq\mathrm{PSPACE}.$$
As a matter of fact, we have
$$\mathrm{DTIME}(f(n))=\mathrm P.$$
In order to see this, let $L$ be a language recognized by a TM $M$ working in time $f(n)$. Put
$$e_M(n)=\min\{k:\text{$M$ terminates in time $\le n^k$ for every input of length $n$}\}.$$
Then $e_M$ is a recursive function, and $e_M(n)\le h(n)$. Thus, $e_M$ is bounded, which means that $M$ actually runs in polynomial time, and $L\in\mathrm P$.

Comment: This follows from the Union-Theorem of McCreight and Meyer, too.